# Callbacks from module

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn go so I decided to make a go module. It works but now I want the main program to get notified when changes happen. In this example I just monitor when connected, but later on for many more changes in the device controlled.

The code below works but I can't see changes that happend in the module, for example the function "onHpd1Connected" in the main program is called when connected but shows that my connection is nil (even if I can see it is set in the "emit" function). The code must be compatible with multiple devices connected (hpd1, hpd2 etc..). I've tried pointers in different ways but without any luck. What I'm I doing wrong, and is this the best way to do it? Or would channels be a better option?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sandbox/hyperdeck"
)

type hdc struct {
    client hyperdeck.Hyperdeck
}

var hpd1 = hdc{
    client: hyperdeck.NewHyperdeck("10.0.20.5", 9993),
}

func (hd hdc) onHpd1Connected() {
    fmt.Println("Connected 1")
    fmt.Println(hd)
}

func main() {
    hpd1.client.On("connected", hpd1.onHpd1Connected)
    hpd1.client.Connect()
}
```

and the module

```
package hyperdeck

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

const (
    Open       ConnectionState = 1
    Connecting ConnectionState = 2
    Closed     ConnectionState = 3
)

type ConnectionState int
type HdCallback func()

type Hyperdeck struct {
    Ip          string
    Port        int
    connection  net.Conn
    state       ConnectionState
    initialized bool
    listeners   map[string][]HdCallback
}

func (hd *Hyperdeck) connect() error {
    if hd.state != Closed {
        return errors.New("already connected to server: " + hd.Ip)
    }
    hd.initialized = false
    hd.state = Connecting
    var err error
    hd.connection, err = net.DialTimeout("tcp", hd.Ip+":"+strconv.Itoa(hd.Port), time.Duration(time.Second*2))
    if err != nil {
        hd.state = Closed
        return err
    } else {
        hd.state = Open
        hd.emit("connected")
    }
    return nil
}

func (hd Hyperdeck) Connect() {
    for {
        if !hd.Connected() {
            err := hd.connect()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}

func (hd *Hyperdeck) Connected() bool {
    return hd.state == Open && hd.connection != nil
}

func (hd Hyperdeck) emit(event string, params ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(hd)
    if listeners, exists := hd.listeners[event]; exists {
        in := make([]reflect.Value, len(params))
        for k, param := range params {
            in[k] = reflect.ValueOf(param)
        }
        for _, cb := range listeners {
            reflect.ValueOf(cb).Call(in)
        }
    }
}

func NewHyperdeck(ip string, port int) Hyperdeck {
    hd := Hyperdeck{
        Ip:          ip,
        Port:        port,
        initialized: false,
        connection:  nil,
        listeners:   map[string][]HdCallback{},
        state:       Closed,
    }
    return hd
}

func (hd Hyperdeck) On(event string, callback func()) {
    if _, exists := hd.listeners[event]; !exists {
        hd.listeners[event] = make([]HdCallback, 0)
    }
    hd.listeners[event] = append(hd.listeners[event], callback)
}
```

Comment: Use a pointer receiver: `func (hd *hdc) onHpd1Connected()`

Comment: The `Connect` method too should have a pointer receiver, I believe: `func (hd *Hyperdeck) Connect()`

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, the Connect pointer reciever solved it, I had already tried it on the onHpd1Connected. So is this the right way to do callbacks?

Comment: Technically speaking this has nothing to do with callbacks. Say, if your callback was just `func() { println("hi!") }` (not dependant on any state) then it would work the same whether or not you used pointers. However, what you are actually trying to do is to effectively share state between separate processes, isn't it? And how else would you achieve that, in Go, other than by knowing and sharing the address of that state? Since Go is pass-by-value – this includes method receivers – there just is no other way.

Comment: Note that there are constructs in Go (maps, slices, ifaces, non-pointer structs with pointer fields, etc.) that make it *look like* you are sharing state without pointers, but that's only how it looks, underneath, somewhere, there's a pointer that allows it all to work.